# Есть кнопка, нужно создать такую же и приписать к ней свой функционал js

Tags: javascript

Кнопка

```
<button type="submit" class="button--primary button button--icon button--icon--reply">
   <span class="button-text">Отправить</span>
</button>
```

И чтобы кнопка не отправляла текст

Comment: лучше через input type+"submit" value="ОТправить"

Comment: Я не могу изменить функционал

Comment: и...что именно Вас сдерживает? Непонятно в чем именно вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

А в чём проблема? Удалите начинку, оставьте стили:

```
<button class="button--primary button button--icon button--icon--reply">
   <span>Отправить</span>
</button>
```

И повесьте на неё нужную вам функцию JavaScript:

```
<button onclick="myFunction()" class="button--primary button button--icon button--icon--reply">
   <span>Отправить</span>
</button>
```

Comment: проблема в том, что я не могу изменять код, а исключительно через добавление js с помощью сторонего приложения

Comment: @дефолт. откройте подробную информацию о странице и во вкладке source поменяйте js вручную